# Automatically delete MEDIA_ROOT between tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I was wondering if it were possible, and preferably not too difficult, to use Django DiscoverRunner to delete my media directory between every test, including once at the very beginning and once at the very end. I was particularly interested in the new attributes "test_suite" and "test_runner" that were introduced in Django 1.7 and was wondering if they would make this task easier.

I was also wondering how I can make the test specific MEDIA_ROOT a temporary file, currently I have a regular MEDIA_ROOT called "media" and a testing MEDIA_ROOT called "media_test" and I use rmtree in setup and tearDown of every test class that involves the media directory. The way I specify which MEDIA_ROOT to use is in my test.py settings file, currenly I just have:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = normpath(join(DJANGO_ROOT, 'media_test'))
```

Is there a way I can set MEDIA_ROOT to a temporary directory named "media" instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution I have found that works is to simply delete it in setUp / tearDown, I would prefer finding some way to make it automatically apply to all tests instead of having to put the logic in every test file that involves media, but I have not figured out how to do that yet.

The code I use is:

```
from shutil import rmtree
from django.conf import settings
from django.test import TestCase

class MyTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        rmtree(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, ignore_errors=True)

    def tearDown(self):
        rmtree(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, ignore_errors=True)
```

The reason I do it in both setUp and tearDown is because if I only have it in setUp I might end up with a lingering media_test directory, and even though it won't be checked in to GitHub by accident (it's in the .gitignore) it still takes up unnecessary space in my project explorer and I just prefer not having it sit there taking up space. If I only have it in tearDown then I risk causing problems if I quit out of the tests part way through and it tries to run a test that involves media while the media from the terminated test still lingers.

Comment: I agree with the use of Setup and TeadDown.  But, its rarely a good idea to have blind removal of folders on a file system!  You could override parts of the TestCase class in your __init__ file to make a true global version of TestCase that does what you want.  But, I hope your testing other parts of your code that dont need/want this modification.  Which makes Setup/Teardown just for the classes that need it the best practice.  But see my answer below for a safer solution.

Answer (score 10):

This question is a bit old, my answer is from Django 2.0 and Python 3.6.6 or later.  Although I think the technique works on older versions too, YMMV.

I think this is a much more important question than it gets credit for!  When you write good tests, its only a matter of time before you need to whip up test files, or generate test files.  Either way, your in danger of polluting the File System of your server or developer machine.  ***Neither is desirable***!

I think the write up on [this page](https://swapps.com/blog/testing-files-with-pythondjango/) is a best-practice.  I'll copy/paste the code snippet below if you don't care about the reasoning (more notes afterwards):

### ----

First, let’s write a basic, really basic, model

```
from django.db import models

class Picture(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField()
```

Then, let’s write a really, really basic, test.

```
from PIL import Image
import tempfile
from django.test import TestCase
from .models import Picture
from django.test import override_settings

def get_temporary_image(temp_file):
    size = (200, 200)
    color = (255, 0, 0, 0)
    image = Image.new("RGBA", size, color)
    image.save(temp_file, 'jpeg')
    return temp_file

class PictureDummyTest(TestCase):

    @override_settings(MEDIA_ROOT=tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(prefix='mediatest').name)
    def test_dummy_test(self):
            temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
            test_image = get_temporary_image(temp_file)
            #test_image.seek(0)
            picture = Picture.objects.create(picture=test_image.name)
            print "It Worked!, ", picture.picture
            self.assertEqual(len(Picture.objects.all()), 1)
```

### ----

I made one important change to the code snippet: ***TemporaryDirectory().name***.  The original snippet used ***gettempdir()***. The **TemporaryDirectory** function creates a new folder with a system generated name every time its called.  That folder will be removed by the OS - but we don't know when!  This way, we get a new folder each run, so no chance of name conflicts.  Note I had to add the .name element to get the name of the generated folder, since MEDIA_ROOT has to be a string.  Finaly, I added **prefix='mediatest'** so all the generated folders are easy to identify in case I want to clean them up in a script.

Also potentially useful to you, is how the settings over-ride can be easy applied to a test class, not just one test function.  See [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.override_settings) for details.

Also note in the comments after this article some people show an even easier way to get a temp file name without worrying about media settings using **NamedTemporaryFile** *(only valid for tests that don't use Media settings!)*.

Answer (score 5):

[The answer by Richard Cooke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52334824/1957741) works but leaves the temporary directories lingering in the file system, at least on Python 3.7 and Django 2.2. This can be avoided by using a combination of setUpClass, tearUpClass and overriding the settings in the test methods. For example:

```
import tempfile
class ExampleTestCase(TestCase):
    temporary_dir = None

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.temporary_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
        super(ExampleTestCase, cls).setUpClass()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.temporary_dir = None
        super(ExampleTestCase, cls).tearDownClass()

    def test_example(self):
        with self.settings(MEDIA_ROOT=self.temporary_dir.name):
            # perform a test
            pass
```

This way the temporary files are removed right away you don't need to worry about the name of the temporary directory either. (Of course, if you want you can still use the `prefix` argument in calling tempfile.TemporaryDirectory)

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
TESTING_MODE = True
...
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(DJANGO_ROOT, 'media_test' if TESTING_MODE else 'media')
```

Comment: I already have that part sorted out, I am currently using a separate media directory for testing. I just want to make it a temporary file, the ones that are often semi-transparent in file explorers. The biggest thing I wanted to know was how I can automatically delete MEDIA_ROOT between every test. Similar to how the test database is reset between every test.